# PDF generation from HTML page for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a tool to convert HTML view pages to PDF from Rails. I want the styles to be intact and should be able to identify CSS styles. I have heard of Prince XML and Wicked PDF. I want to know the advantages and disadvantages of using one of them. Also, I want to know whether the rendering of PDF has any problems with regard to the style(whether style will be properly rendered). If there is any other tools, please inform about them.

Thanks,
Prince

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[PDFkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit) is pretty nice from what I've seen, but I'm a big fan of [wicked_pdf](http://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) for the fine-grained control you can get over your documents.

[PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/) and [princely](https://github.com/mbleigh/princely) are great, but expensive. [DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com) is a great web service that can let you dip your toes in, but the only things prince really does better than the free wkhtmltopdf-based solutions are its ability to properly do page-breaks without cutting table rows and repeating headers.

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of wicked_pdf, and good friends with the people who run DocRaptor.

Answer (score 4):

Prince is definitely the best at PDF generation. There's a web service called [DocRaptor.com](http://docraptor.com) that has a partnership with Prince XML. You can use their API to generate PDFs and Excel docs in any language without paying the Prince license fee and without having to download anything.

Answer (score 4):

You can use 'wicked_pdf' gem. It provides very good support to generate pdf using html code.

In controller:

```
def show
  @report = Report.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf => "report",:template => "reports/show"
    end 
  end
end
```

Create a show.pdf.erb and you can write simple html.

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<h1> Report </h1>
<p>
<%= @report.details %>
.................................
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rubyprince,

There are several ways to generate PDFs from within Rails. Railscasts has produced three screencasts of the topic.

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/78-generating-pdf-documents
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit

Personally though if you want to create high quality prints with strong styling I would suggest PrinceXML. The unfortunate part of PrinceXML is the price tag, however you get a lot for the cost. There is a Ruby gem called [princely](https://github.com/mbleigh/princely) that helps you abstract the API into Ruby calls. What I like most about Prince is your ability to generate things that are standard for print material using CSS. Page numbers, table of contents with leaders. I suggest taking a look at the blog article [Creating PDF Documents in Ruby on Rails](http://jimneath.org/2009/02/16/creating-pdf-documents-in-ruby-on-rails/) as well - it's a little old, but the information will give you and idea on what it is like to use PrinceXML.

Comment: Thanks, the first two RailsCasts cannot be used for creating PDF from HTML...PrinceXML is definitely in my top list..

Answer (score 1):

[PDFkit](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit), it uses a WebKit rendering engine([wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)), same as safari. This means you can do any css styling that works in safari. Easy to install and works good.

-webkit-gradient -webkit-border-radius etc etc , til your heart's content :)

note: wicked_pdf also uses wkhtmltopdf, but in my opinion PDFkit is a bit nicer to use.

Answer (score 1):

Flying Saucer is another option for generating pdf.Flying saucer is a java library in rails
you can use [acts_as_flying_saucer](http://github.com/amardaxini/acts_as_flying_saucer) gem or plugin for generating PDF.

Comment: good library and gem..gr8 to hear from the author of the gem itself :)..but I already used PDFKit for the purpose..will try it in the next project :)