# Convert html with svg to pdf

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view, svg, rubygems

I have a view that contains some html plus calls to methods that return svg code. Now , the problem is that I want to make the user able to save the svg part of the view as pdf and I dont seem to find a proper gem to do this. Also is there a way to convert the whole view (html + svg) to pdf ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5194304/684934 might be worth a look

Comment: This is a duplicate question! You asked this 4 hours ago. And I also commented on it. Take a look at your question - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913113/html-to-pdf-gem 

If you find someone doesn't answer your question its because you haven't provided enough detail or done any background research that gives someone fundamental groundings of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Ah Cairo does have a blend mode CAIRO_OPERATOR_MULTIPLY. This could be the best thing I've seen yet. I haven't seen any other pdf/eps generator that does mix-blend-mode multiply. Thanks, https://www.cairographics.org/operators/