# Get HTML code in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any way to get html code of page after executing its correcponding action. I used render_to_string method  [render_to_string](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string). But i think it only gives view code without excuting its action. Please tell me is there anyway to get html code after executing it action in ruby on rails.

```
  html = render_to_string(:layout => false , :action => "show")
```

In show action i have...

```
 def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
 end
```

i have show.html.erb

```
<%= @book.name%>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the full source code of the markup generated by a view-rendering controller action? Can you provide some code related to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: This honestly makes no sense at all. Can you provide _any_ more insight on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Actually i want to export "show file view" in pdf file(Same as it appears in browser).

Comment: You're probably asking the wrong question, then. Outputting a Rails view to PDF can be vastly streamlined by employing a PDF generation library. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194304/pdf-generation-from-html-page-for-rails

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just try this.

```
render :file => "/path/to/some/template.erb"
```

It will fetch entire Html code into your view file